# How to use laravel variable in script

Tags: laravel, input, autocomplete, tags

I want to have to auto complete input tags with list that define with laravel variable and I cannot use it in the script 
I cannot use JSON file or previous defined list
for example with this input

```
<input class="form-control" name="excerpt" value="
          @if (isset($dataTypeContent->tags))
               @foreach($dataTypeContent->tags as $tag)
                   {{$tag->tag_name}}
               @endforeach
          @endif
" >
</input>
```

Comment: You can't just drop everything in the value like that and expect autocomplete functionality to happen.  You would need to use a tool like jquery autocomplete for example.  https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Comment: Note: After `value=` you have a line break. And in your html the input field will be filled with that many number of spaces to cover the line break and your actual content may not be visible in the input box(if you've set fixed width).

Answer (score 0):

using tag-it bootstrap

```
`<form>
 <input name="tags" id="singleFieldTags2">
 </form>
 <script> var taglist = [];</script>
 @if (isset($dataTypeContent->tags))
    @foreach($dataTypeContent->tags as $tag)
 <script>
 fruits.push("{{$tag->tag_name}}");
 </script>
 @endforeach
 @endif
 <script>
    $(function(){
       $('#singleFieldTags2').tagit({
          availableTags: taglist
       });
     });
</script>`
```